# Product of primes divides index of an intersection of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a finite group $(|G|<\infty)$ and $p=[G:H], q=[G:K]$ are primes $p\neq q$. $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$. I want to show that $pq$ divides $[G:H\cap K]$.

So, I know $|G|=|H||G:H| \Rightarrow p=\frac{|G|}{|H|}$ and $q=\frac{|G|}{|K|}$. Also, $[G:H\cap K]=\frac{|G|}{|H\cap K|}$.

Now, $pq=\frac{|G|}{|H|}\frac{|G|}{|K|}=\frac{|G||G|}{|H||K|} \Rightarrow \frac{[G:H\cap K]}{pq}=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K||G|}$.

I do not see how to continue from here. I know I want the quotient to be an integer, but I am not certain of which property I need to use to proceed.

Comment: have you used that $p$ and $q$ are primes?

Comment: I haven't yet. Can you suggest how? I know that a group of prime order is cyclic, but how do I use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In general, for subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$, if $[G:H]$ and $[G:K]$ are relatively prime, then $G=HK$.

Comment: So, $H\cap K$ $\subset K$ and $H\cap K$ $\subset H$ are subgroup(s). So by Lagrange's Thm., $|H\cap K|$ divides $|H|$ and $|K|$. Also, $p,q$ relatively prime, so $|H|$ and $|K|$ are relatively prime. $\Rightarrow |H\cap K|=1$, so $H\cap K=e_G$. Now, use your fact: $|H||K|$ divides $|HK|$. Is this it?

Comment: Well $G=HK$ implies that $[K:H \cap K]=[G:H]$ (using the fact that $|HK|=|H||K|/|H \cap K|$) and then it follows that $[G:H \cap K]=[G:K]\cdot[K:H \cap K]=pq$.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the problem is :

$[G:H]=p\Rightarrow g^p\in H\forall g\in G$

$[G:K]=q\Rightarrow g^q\in K\forall g\in G$

For all obvious reasons $(g^p)^q\in H$ and $(g^q)^p\in K$ i.e., $g^{pq}\in H\cap K$

Can you proceed now? (I have not yet use $p$ and $q$ are primes)